# File Maker Data source name not found, and no default driver specified - pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, pyodbc, pythonanywhere

I deployed my python flask application in #pythonanywhere. Currently while i am executing python program I am getting Data source name not found, and no default driver specified. It is working fine in my local machine. I am using python 3.7 and the database is Filemaker 18 which is an external database server. Normally when this error occured me ni local machine, I tried to configure the DSN namd and database with odbc.ini and ODBC manager of my local machine.

Can any one help to configure my DSN through pythonanywhere.com

Comment: You might want to [ask pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/start_topic/) if they can make the FileMaker ODBC driver available to your application.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will ask